# Xpath select elements that contains a subset of specific list

Tags: xml, xpath

Good day! Assume the following XML:

```
<store>
    <book id="b1"></book>
    <book id="b2"></book>
</store>
<store>
    <book id="b2"></book>
    <book id="b4"></book>
</store>
<booklist>
    <book id="b1"></book>
    <book id="b2"></book>
    <book id="b3"></book>
</booklist>
```

I want to write an Xpath query that will select stores which
has all their books in booklist. In my example it's first store, but not the second.
I've tried
`//store[./book/@id = /booklist/book/@id]`
but it chooses stores which contain at least 1 common book, and not all of them.
Also, didn't found any predicate like "contains" for two node lists, so I'm lack of ideas.

Edit: Im very appreciate any help, but I'd prefer a solution, which uses "basic" Xpath features (if exists). It's a new language for me. Yet, thanks for everyone who is responded so far.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the shortest and simplest so far one-liner XPath expression solution. Explanation is also provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/store[not(book[not(@id = /*/booklist/*/@id)])]
```

**When applied on this XML document** (the provided one, made well-formed by wrapping it with a single top element):

```
<t>
    <store>
        <book id="b1"></book>
        <book id="b2"></book>
    </store>
    <store>
        <book id="b2"></book>
        <book id="b4"></book>
    </store>
    <booklist>
        <book id="b1"></book>
        <book id="b2"></book>
        <book id="b3"></book>
    </booklist>
</t>
```

**the wanted `stor` element is selected**:

```
<store>
   <book id="b1"/>
   <book id="b2"/>
</store>
```

**Verification using XSLT as the host of XPath**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/*/store[not(book[not(@id = /*/booklist/*/@id)])]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this XSLT transformation is applied on the above XML document, the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<store>
   <book id="b1"/>
   <book id="b2"/>
</store>
```

**Explanation**:

The expression:

```
/*/store[not(book[not(@id = /*/booklist/*/@id)])]
```

means:

Select all `store` elements (children of the top element) such that there is not even a single `book` (child) in them whose `id` attribute's value is one of the `id` attributes values of the `book`s (children) of `booklist`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that will work

```
//store[not(book/@id = //store/book[not(@id = //booklist/book/@id)]/@id)]
```

applied to this xml (store `name` added for clarity in testing) it selects stores `1` & `3`

```
<xml>
  <store name="1">
    <book id="b1"/>
    <book id="b2"/>
  </store>
  <store name="2">
    <book id="b2"/>
    <book id="b4"/>
  </store>
  <store name="3">
    <book id="b1"/>
    <book id="b3"/>
  </store>
  <store name="4">
    <book id="b3"/>
    <book id="b4"/>
  </store>
  <booklist>
    <book id="b1"/>
    <book id="b2"/>
    <book id="b3"/>
  </booklist>
</xml>
```

Explanation (two negatives make a positive)

```
//store[not(book/@id = # get me all stores that don't have a book/@id that is in the list below
//store/book[not(@id = //booklist/book/@id)]/@id) # get me a list of store/book/@id where @id is not in the book list
]
```

Comment: Yes, thats the kind of solution I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to use functions, try this:

```
for $bid in //booklist/book/@id 
  if(every $id in //store/book/@id satisfies $id=$bid ) then fn:true()
  else fn:false()
```

not sure it works, but just give you an idea.

Comment: It's an interesing approach. Since I'm new to Xpath, it's my first exposure to functions in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to think it was possible using the exslt set extensions

E.g.:

```
//store[count(./book/@id) = count(set:intersection(./book/@id,//booklist/book/@id))]
```

But `intersection` doesn't seem to do what I expect it to within python's `lxml.etree`