# Xpath - select stores that each list of book contains it

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a problem with a specific XPath query. It is very similar to SO question:  [Xpath select elements that contains a subset of specific list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465457/xpath-select-elements-that-contains-a-subset-of-specific-list)

I my case, the XML looks like this.

```
<x>
    <stores>
        <store>
            <book>b1</book>
        </store>
        <store>
            <book>b2</book>
        </store>
        <store>
                <book>b4</book>
        </store>
    </stores>
    <Lists>
        <List>
            <wanted>
                <book>b1</book>
                <book>b2</book>
            </wanted>
        </List>
        <List>
            <wanted>
                <book>b1</book>
                <book>b4</book>
            </wanted>
        </List> 
        <List>
            <wanted>
                <book>b1</book>
            </wanted>
        </List>
    </Lists>
</x>
```

One important thing is that the element `book` for a store is a key so it is unique.

I am after an Xpath query that will select stores which have their book in all List. So in this example it should be only the store with book `b1`.

I have formulated a query like this

```
/*/store[not(book[not(. = //wanted/book)])]
```

but it selects every store which occurred at least one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all stores such that there is *no* `List` that does *not* contain this store's book.  I don't *think* this can be done in pure XPath 1.0 because it would require access within an inner predicate to the element matched by the outer expression

```
/x/stores/store[not(/x/Lists/List[wanted/book != $outer/book])]
            ^
       This store is $outer
```

In XPath 2.0 you could use `every`

```
/x/stores/store[every $list in /x/Lists/List satisfies $list/wanted/book = book]
```

Comment: @user3080997 would you mind accepting Ian's answer. You can earn a few points for that, if it helps!

Comment: @ϹοδεMεδιϲ yes, of course. It was my first question here, and iam not used to every function.